# How to extract parts of a bzipped PostgreSQL dump

Tags: postgresql, psql, bz2

I have a PostgreSQL plain format dump and need only two or three tables' data. The dump is in gz2 format.

```
bzcat dump.sql.gz | perl -lne 'print if /^COPY tablename/../^\\\.$/' > something.sql
```

not working. also tried

```
bzip2 -dc dump.sql.gz|perl -lne 'print if /^COPY tablename/../^\\\.$/' > something.sql
```

The dump file is more than 30GB.

Comment: `awk` might be easier to use than Perl.

Comment: Is there any way to get a dump in custom or directory format?  This would be trivial with those formats.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working".  What error are you getting, or what wrong answer are you getting?

Comment: not working is that the command keeps running in the terminal and never stop and the sql file is zero bytes only

Answer (score 0):

The table name probably needs to be schema-qualified.

```
whatever_cat | perl -lne 'print if /^COPY public\.tablename/../^\\\.$/'
```

This will depend on the version of pg_dump being used.  The change actually kicks in in a bug-fix release, is it was the result of a security concern (CVE-2018-1058)